# Is it possible to return the output (html) of a particular controller's action?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using spring 3.0 MVC:

Is it possible to programatically execute a controller's action, and return the generated output (the html)?

I want to take that output and store it in the database.

Comment: That's far too vague a question, please give a specific example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is possible. Have you ever written a jUnit test for a controller? Mocking the request and the response would be one way of doing it.
Another way is using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and simulating a browser:

```
    GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://httpcomponents.apache.org");
    // execute method and handle any error responses.
    ...
    InputStream in = get.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    // Process the data from the input stream.
    get.releaseConnection();
```

This code is from this [page](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/get.html).